# Too many tabs in Chrome causes whole computer to freeze

Tags: arch-linux, cinnamon, freeze, processes

When I open too many (more than ~8/9) tabs in Chrome the whole GUI freezes and the mouse pointer doesn't move and the system responds incredibly slowly to keyboard input (~20s delay). I'm assuming it's all down to lack of RAM on my laptop but I haven't been able to check this when it actually happens due to the nature of the problem.

What I want to be able to do is press a special key combination which instantly kills Chrome.

I'm running: Arch Linux/ Cinnamon on a Lenovo X200 if that helps at all.

Comment: how much RAM do you have? can you upgrade the RAM in your laptop?  according to https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Laptops/Can-X200-handle-8GB-memory/td-p/124209 it can handle 8GB RAM.  To use more than 3GB, though, you need to have installed the 64-bit version of Arch (or use a PAE kernel).

Comment: If your system has bogged down, you may not have resources left to launch gnome system monitor (which isn't particularly lightweight).

Comment: DK you're absolutely right, I'll rephrase my question

Comment: i've emachines amd el1332 3g RAM , this happen with me on many differente linux os with different env's (gnome/kde...) ,  until i successfully install nvidia from nvidia website ! i think the same with you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alt-Sysrq-F should help you if you're already in the trouble and system is very slow due to search for any free memory bits. But it's better to add more RAM especially with modern browser applications, which become more and more bigger due to support of many new web standards. As an alternative, you can increase your swap space.